# Azure: Is it possible to chose the ambari instance while creating an R cluster?

Tags: azure, hadoop, ambari

**What I'm doing**
I'm working on Microsoft Azure, and here is the thing. I'm trying to create an R cluster on azure with hadoop 3.6 but I need some default tools like nifi, kafka and storm which are available on an HDF.

**Problem**
When I create the cluster, I can't chose the instance of ambari so I tried to create the cluster with a template which I activate every morning to create the cluster and another one to delete the cluster every night. I was wondering if it's possible to chose the Ambari instance while using the template.

anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot change the version of Ambari. Since it comes by default with HDI versions.

You can find more details on this documentation regarding [Hadoop components available with different HDInsight versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-component-versioning).

Comment: The probleme is that i have the version 3.6 of HDI but can't see kafka and storm on ambari. And do you know a way to use nifi on the cluster ?